# How can I boost the volume of my Video

Tags: video, audio, editing, processing

I have a video that I need to pass on to some of my friends but it has very low audio volume.

How can I boost the audio volume in this video so that it has a similar level as my other videos? Is there a video converter that can boost the audio volume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](http://forum.videohelp.com/topic270267.html) forum. It helped me once.
You will need

[Goldwave](http://www.videohelp.com/tools?tool=GoldWave)

[virtualdub (or Mod)](http://www.videohelp.com/tools?tool=Virtualdub)

[Lame MP3 Codec](http://www.videohelp.com/tools?tool=Lame_MP3) (or any other Audio Compression codec)

Comment: +1 for VirtualDub. It's a great open-source video editor.

Answer (score 1):

From [How to increase Video Sound Levels on AVI. Files or Mpeg](http://www.videohelp.com/forum/archive/how-to-increase-video-sound-levels-on-avi-files-or-mpeg-t262216.html):

> If the files are only for watching
>   once or twice i use ONLY [virtualdub](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/VirtualDub.htm),
>   very easy.
>
> 1. Open file in virtualdub
> 2. Click on Video -> Direct Stream Copy
> 3. Click Audio -> Full Processing Mode
> 4. Click Audio -> Volume, then check "Adjust Volume of Audio Channels" and
>      set the slider to for example 303%.
> 5. Click File -> Save as AVI, enter a new filename and Ok.
>
> Thats all, and you dont even have to
>   know theres something called demux and
>   mux. But! the file will be big as the
>   audio is now uncompressed, not very
>   suitable for archiving.
>
> Edit: If its an Mpeg you need to leave
>   Video in Full Processing Mode (unless
>   you got a lot of harddisk space or a
>   short video) and set a compression (i
>   would recommend XVid) under the menu
>   Video -> Compression. This will take
>   quite a bit longer time btw.

Comment: This can be used in the reverse also if you need to decrease the volume of a video.