# How can I boost audio on an MP4 downloaded YouTube video under Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, audio, video-editing

I have [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb7Y-_031FE) which has audio that is way too soft. It's there, and audible, but quiet enough to be hard to understand. Basically, I am looking for what [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/51794/how-can-i-boost-the-volume-of-my-video) provides, only for Linux rather than Windows.

My initial research covered [a YouTube video which explained what I want to do from within YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VcfA3nWKNQ) hinges on a button to the bottom right of the screen saying, "Try the YouTube video editor" which is not displayed now. I have not been able to find my way into the subsequently shown audio tweaking interface.

(I have the video on my machine in original MOV format. I also have intermittent access to a Mac.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `ffmpeg` can change the audio of a file

If your file is named `video.mp4`, you could use:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -af "volume=2" output.mp4
```

to double the output audio volume. Note this will re-encode your audio, possibly changing the codec; use `-c:a` to set whichever audio codec you like.

The above command will also work just fine on the original MOV that you have, and you should probably use that if you are concerned about quality as YouTube *might* have re-encoded the audio (and will almost definitely have re-encoded the video).

You may have to test to find how much you want to 'boost' the audio by, depending on what the input is like and how loud you want it.

Note that `ffmpeg` by design doesn't do in-place editing of files.

## Example Output

[image: not boosted] [image: boosted]

Unboosted on left, boosted on right. Above produced using [`ahistogram`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ahistogram).

There is more info in the [`ffmpeg` filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html), see the [`volume` audio filter section](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume).

Comment: fyi, it seems this command only works for .mp4, and not for .mov

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, you can increase the volume of 5 videos per day.

https://online-video-cutter.com/volume

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).